# Как удалить последний текст \r\n ,

Tags: c#

Вид текста из ресурсов:

```
  "vk.com\r\ninstagramr\r\nok.ru\r\nbadoo.com\r\n"
  "vk.com\r\ninstagramr\r\nok.ru\r\nbadoo.com\r" - или так
```

Использую следующий код для добавления текста

```
var Data = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < DataListBox.Items.Count; i++)
{
   Data.AppendLine($"{DataListBox.Items[i]}");
}
if (Data.Length > 0) 
{ 
   Data.Length--; // при этом получается так в конце \r
}
```

Вопрос как убрать последние `\r` и `\r\n`

Попробовал добавить после `Data.Length--;`

```
Data = Data.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

на выходе получаю такое: `"vk.cominstagramok.rubadoo.com"`

Comment: А зачем так сложно? Не проще сделать так `var result = "vk.com\r\ninstagramr\r\nok.ru\r\nbadoo.com\r".Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Этот текст я добавляю в файл, на выходе получаю строки а в конце добавляется `\r\n` вот пытаюсь удалять последние строки с `\r\n` а предыдущие переходы на новую строчку оставить

Comment: Если вы добавляете в файл, то все еще проще `List<string> lines = new() { "строка 1" }; lines.Add("строка 2"); File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", lines);` и обратно `var lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");`. Если добавить в уже существующий файл, то `.AppendAllLines(...)`. Сам фреймворк запишет как надо и прочитает как надо.

Comment: `Data.Length -= 2`

Comment: Не забудьте принять ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str.TrimEnd('\n')
   .TrimEnd('\r');
```

Может быть важно: методы семейства Trim создают новую строку, а не меняют старую.

так же можно написать

```
str.TrimEnd();
```

который просто уберет все "пустые символы" с конца строки:

- пробел
- переход на следующую строку ( `\n` )
- перевод каретки( `\r` )
- таб ( `\t` )
- и др. Полный список пустых символов можно посмотреть в  [документации к методу Char.IsWhiteSpace.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-5.0) (подсказал Andrey NOP)

Comment: Должно быть достаточно простого `.Trim()`.

Comment: По идее можно даже `str.TrimEnd('\n', '\r')` если автору порядок не принципиален. Ну и надо добавить, что этот метод создаёт новую строку и не меняет старую

Comment: @EvgeniyZ только трим может убрать символы на начале строки на сколько я помню

Comment: @Andrew, к сожаление это не помогло. У меня в `if (Data.Length > 0) {  Data.Length--; }` тут играет больше роль, тут удаляется последняя `\n` а остаётся `\r`, мне нужно дополнительно убрать эту строку `\r`

Comment: не знаю что у тебя не получается ибо этот код в любом случае убирает последние \n и \r. Если не важен порядок - попробуй `str.TrimEnd('\n', '\r')` как написал Андрей Ноп

Comment: Я балда) разобрался, не там вписал))

Comment: @Andrew Мое замечание было больше к тому, что сам метод `.Trim()` (любой вариации), убирает все лишние пробелы и отступы в конце/начале текста, без указания каких-либо параметров. А уже где "резать", это выбор каждого, хотите в конце, пожалуйста `.TrimEnd()` без параметров. [Вот простой пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dSUWie). Указывать конкретно символы нужно в том случае, если надо убрать нестандартный символ (например все `-` в конце, тогда да `.TrimEnd('-')`).

Comment: @ZidoX, кнопка для принятия ответа слева под кнопками для голосования

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, точнее "все пробельные символы", к которым относятся в т.ч. табы и переносы строк :)

Comment: пожалуй запишу замечания в сам ответ что бы люди не читали комментарии

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, для демонстрации более наглядно, если использовать Regex.Escape: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UPM3ya :)

Comment: @Andrew, не думаю, что это важно, но полный список пробельных символов есть здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=net-5.0#remarks

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хм, а зачем он перед пробелами ставит слэш? А так да, я думал о нем, но чет не стал, думаю и так видна прекрасно лишняя строка пустая)